# gorm is not mapping db values to entity

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Hi Below is the Entity class and structure of my postgresql table.
The find query of gorm returns the desired number of rows but the object doesn't get updated with the values.

entity:

```
type Flow struct {
Id             int                    `gorm:"primary_key";"AUTO_INCREMENT"; "column:id"`
Name           string                 `gorm:"type:varchar(200)"; "column:name"`
Version        string                 `gorm:"column:version"`
Type           enum.FlowType          `gorm:"column:type"`
Status         flow_status.FlowStatus `gorm:"column:status"`
UniqueMmid     uuid.UUID              `gorm:"type:varchar(36)"; "column:uniquemmid"`
SomeXYVersions *[]uint8               `gorm:"column:somexyzversions"`
CreatedOn      time.Time              `gorm:"column:createdon"`
DeletedOn      time.Time              `gorm:"column:deletedon"`
}
```

Table structure:

```
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id             | integer                     |           | not null | 
nextval('flows_id_seq'::regclass)
 name           | character varying           |           | not null | 
 version        | character varying           |           | not null | 
 type           | character varying           |           | not null | 
 status         | character varying           |           | not null | 
 uniquemmid     | uuid                        |           | not null | 
 somexyversions | json                        |           |          | 
 createdon      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 deletedon      | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 Indexes:
    "flows_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I am using gorm ORM. Below code shows how I am trying to fetch the db record:

```
flow := &model.Flow{UniqueMmid: uuid.FromStringOrNil(xyzid)}
dbConnection.Debug().First(&flow)
```

When I check the flow object it contains no values.
Can someone please help me find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must send address of your variable to First function.

But you are sending pointer of pointer. Correct way is;

```
dbConnection.Debug().First(flow)
```

Comment: That doesn't help.

Comment: and it's supposed to be this way only. check this out: https://medium.com/remotepanda-blog/go-with-gorm-chapter-10-golang-91bc5d01c161